# Predict individual data from aggregated data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, bias

I'm trying to construct a model in order to establish a relation between the non performing loans of an specific bank and the non performing loans of the entire system. Since the data of the latter includes the specific bank that I'm studying, I would like to know if such an approach would give valuable information.  If possible, I'm interested in quantifying the possible bias and how could I test this approach.

Comment: Do you have data on both the specific bank and the other banks?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the individual information of the other banks.

Comment: The answer depends of how large is the share of non-performing loans of a specific bank in the whole system. If it is in low percents (up to 5), you could say that the specific bank does not influence the whole system. In this case you can model the dependence without any restriction. If however the specific bank is influential, then two models will be needed, one for causal relationship between specific bank loans and the whole system, and the reverse relationship.

Comment: The share of the bank is up to 2%, so it seems there is no significant influence. Though, it would be useful to quantify this conclusion.